# 64 GB RAM installed but only 32 GB Usable

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have an MSI B450 Tomahawk Motherboard and 2 sticks of RAM, 32GB each Corsair Vengeance LPX 3200MHZ (2x 32GB). The sticks are in slots 2 and 4.

The operating system is Windows 10 Pro (64 bit).

Windows sees the full 64 GB, but shows only 32 GB as usable.

Usable Memory Screenshot

[image]

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your memory modules, part number(s) **CMK64GX4M4B3200C16** appear on the [QVL](https://www.build-gaming-computers.com/is-memory-qvl-important.html) provided for [your motherboard](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B450-TOMAHAWK#support-mem-14), and is marked as compatible with your current processor.

However, the maximum speed you'll get with the kit (as per [SPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect) defaults) will be 2133MHz.

To gain access to faster 2933MHz in single rank mode and 2400Mhz in dual rank mode if 2 out of 4 DRAM slots are populated, as referenced in [this article](https://www.pugetsystems.com/blog/2018/06/06/2nd-Gen-AMD-Ryzen-Supported-RAM-Speeds-1175/) by Puget Systems, enable A-XMP, and select XMP Profile 2 in your BIOS settings.

You may want to move the RAM sticks around, as recommended by @Silbee in the comments below, ie to slots DIMMA2 (Slot 2) and DIMMB2 (Slot 4) to enable dual channel memory mode.

Comment: DIMMA2 (second slot) has to be filled first. For dual channel you also have to populate DIMMB2 (fourth slot). So he has no choice there.

Comment: Wow, that worked, thanks for the info!

Comment: @Silbee I swapped them around, so the one in the 4th slot went into the 2nd and the one in the 2nd went into the 4th. Looks to be working fine